# Adaptor pattern in golang

Tags: go, design-patterns, adaptor

Trying to create adaptor pattern in Golang, Not sure where I am doing wrong. My client.go showing an error
`c.broker.placeOrder undefined (type exchange.Exchange has no field or method placeOrder)`

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "oms/consumer"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    consumer.Consumer(ctx)
}
```

consumer.go

```
package consumer

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "oms/broker"
)

func Consumer(ctx context.Context) {
    broker.Execute()
}
```

client.go

```
package broker

import (
    "oms/broker/exchange"
)
type Client struct {
    broker exchange.Exchange
}

func (c *Client) SetBroker(broker exchange.Exchange) {
    c.broker = broker
}

func (c *Client) placeOrder(id string, quantity, price int) {
// I am getting error here
    c.broker.placeOrder(id, quantity, price)
}
```

broker.go

```
package broker

// create a Client and set its broker to Paytm
import (
    "oms/broker/paytm"
)

func Execute() {
    client := &Client{}
    client.SetBroker(paytm.Paytm{ /* fields */ })
    client.placeOrder("order1", 10, 100)
}
```

exchange.go

```
package exchange

type Exchange interface {
    placeOrder(id string, quantity, price int)
}
```

paytm.go

```
package paytm

import "oms/broker/exchange"

type Paytm struct {
    // fields
}

func (p Paytm) placeOrder(id string, quantity, price int) {
    // implementation for Paytm's placeOrder method
}
```

Comment: Lowercase names are only visible inside a package. `exchange.Exhange.placeOrder` is not visible outside the exchange package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call an unexported method from your `broker` package.
If you want to call the method from outside of the `paytm` package you should rename it to `PlaceOrder` in your interface, as well as your method.

More information on exported/unexported fields and methods can be found e.g. here: https://golangbyexample.com/exported-unexported-fields-struct-go/